# Android - Call AsyncTask at the end of an animation

Tags: android, animation, android-asynctask

I have asynctask that gathers text from a database. The text slides into view with an animation. Then a Hander waits about 5 seconds and it slides the text out of view using an animation and then calls the asynctask again. The problem is that the asynctask gathers the information before the TextView is finished completing its slide out animation. I want to call the asynctask once the animation is done. But when I place the code into the animationEnd I get an error. How can I achieve this?

This is what I am trying to attempt.

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if(animation == slideOut){
    new gatherText().execute();
    }
}
```

`new gatherText().execute()` is my AsyncTask that I am trying to call from the `onAnimationEnd()` The onAnimationEnd is outside of the `onCreate()` because it has to be. I am not sure how I can reference the AsyncTask outside of the `onCreate()`.

Comment: It says `new gatherText().execute()` can not be resolved as a type.

Comment: Where is your AsyncTask declared?

Comment: It is declared in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: What is the name of your async task class?